# eigenvector update formula

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, matrix-theory

Suppose that $B$ is a Hermitian matrix with one known eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$. (assume its the smallest or largest pair, if you like). Form the rank one update $B+\rho bb^{T}$.

Now I'm interested in a (possibly approximate) formula for the updated eigenpair $(\widetilde{\lambda},\widetilde{v})$, that depends only on the entries of $B$ and $\lambda,v$. There are such formulas derived in a classic 1978 paper by Bunch, Nielsen and Sorensen (building on an earlier classic work by Golub), but they involve the full eigenbasis of $B$.

Any pointers?

P.S.
(Assume $\lambda,\widetilde{\lambda}$ are simple, to keep things simple).

Comment: By $A$ do you mean $B$? Edit: You will probably also want to know quantitatively how `simple' $\lambda$ is, for example something like the distance to its nearest eigenvalue neighbor.

Comment: I changed $A$ to $B$, thanks!

I think I can obtain this information - what next? I eagerly await further enlightenment! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a first-order approximation.
I'll write $\tilde{v} = v + \rho w + O(\rho^2)$ and $\tilde{\lambda} = \lambda + \rho \mu + O(\rho^2)$.  We may assume $\|v\| = \|\tilde{v}\| = 1$, so $v^T w = 0$.   If $\lambda$ is a simple eigenvalue of $B$, $B - \lambda I$ is invertible on the orthogonal complement $v^\perp$ of $v$.  Taking $(B + \rho b b^T) \tilde{v} = \tilde{\lambda} \tilde{v}$ to first order in $\rho$, we have
$$ B w + b b^T v = \mu v + \lambda w $$
Let $c = b - (b^T v) v$ which is orthogonal to $v$, so that this equation splits into
$$ B w + (b^T v) c = \lambda w \ \text{and} (b^T v)^2 v = \mu v$$
Thus $\mu = (b^T v)^2$ and $w = - (b^T v) (B - \lambda I)|_{v^\perp}^{-1} c$.

Higher-order approximations along the same lines should be possible.